# Node js using "this" from function call within module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, this

I am calling a local function from within a `module.exports` function. How can I access the `exports` `this` object?

```
exports.myVar = 'foo'

exports.myFunc = function() {
  localFunc()
}

function localFunc() {
  console.log(this.myVar) //Undefined
}
```

I have tried using `localFunc().bind(this)` but this does not work either. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what do you want `this` to be?

Comment: I want `this` to be `foo`

Comment: Where is `foo`?

Comment: Do you mean you want `this` to be `exports`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two ways can  resolve you issue.

the first:

```
exports.myVar = 'foo'

exports.myFunc = function() {
  that = this;
  localFunc(that)
}
function localFunc(that) {
  console.log(that.myVar) //foo
}
```

the second

```
exports.myVar = 'foo'

exports.myFunc = function() {
  localFunc()
}

localFunc = ()=> {
  console.log(this.myVar) //foo
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is what i do:

```
function localFunc() {
   const self = exports;
   console.log(self.myVar);
}

exports.myVar = 'foo';

exports.myFunc = function () {
    localFunc();
}
```

Comment: or you can just use `exports.myVar` directly

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var data = module.exports = {
  myVar: 'foo',

  myFunc: function() {
    localFunc();
  }
}

function localFunc() {
  console.log(data.myVar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `exports`. Or declare `myVar` to be a variable, assign it to the exports and create a closure around it for `localFunc`.

`this` only really makes sense when you are event binding and/or creating objects.

Comment: `localFunc` is really a private function to this module so I don't want it exported. Can you provide an example closure you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

localFunc.bind(*this*) just returns a new function which is the localFunc function, but with *this* bound to whatever you put in the parentheses. You need to actually assign the new function (returned by localFunc.bind) back to localFunc. Here are two simple examples:

```
exports.myVar = 'foo';

exports.myFunc = function() {
    localFunc = localFunc.bind(this);
    localFunc();
};

function localFunc() {
    console.log(this.myVar);
}
```

or:

```
exports.myVar = 'foo';

exports.myFunc = function() {
    localFunc();
};

function localFunc() {
    console.log(this.myVar);
}
localFunc = localFunc.bind(exports);
```

The 2nd option is probably better than the first because in the first example, you have to rebind the function every time exports.myFunc is called.